# can anyone help me with this macro?

Tags: c, macros

Anyone can explain **in details** what the following macro does?

```
#define write_XDATA(address,value) (((char *)0x010000) [address]=value)
```

thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use it:

```
write_XDATA( Address, Value );
```

and it is expanded:

```
((char*)0x010000)[Address]=Value;
```

which is equivalent to the following:

```
char* baseAddress = (char*)0x010000;
*(baseAddress + Address) = Value;
```

so basically it writes a byte stored in `Value` at the address `0x010000 + Address`.

Answer (score 2):

It assigns `value` to the byte at memory location `0x10000 + address`. It's easier to grok if you separate it out a bit:

```
char* buf = (char *)0x010000;
buf[address]=value;
```

(Though of course you have no choice but to mash it all together in a macro.)

Comment: Not necessarily. Why could you not write a function that accepts a `char` and a `size_t` and writes that `char` at address 0x010000 + size_t?

Comment: Sorry, my last statement was ambiguous. What I meant was, "...in a macro, you have no choice...".

Answer (score 1):

That's most probably part of a program designed to run on an embedded platform. It's used to do memory mapped IO.

The base address of the register-map is 0x010000. It writes `value` to the memory location `0x010000+address`.

The use of the square brackets `[]` works because of the equivalence of array-addressing and pointer arithmetic in C.

Answer (score 0):

It maps addresses to real addresses using an offset and then writes to it.  XDATA is probably a term taken over from the 8051-processor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much details you want to hear,
but the macro expands itself to what you have just written -

macro parameters address and value are put into *address* and *value* placeholders in the macro expansion definition (((char *)0x010000) [address]=value)

Answer (score 0):

This macro on `address + 0x010000` saving one byte of value.